# Is it possible to change mouse pointer in UWP app

Tags: uwp, mouse-cursor

Is it possible to change or even hide the mouse-pointer in a UWP app?
The only thing I can find is this :

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;
```

But in UWP, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes this can be done by settings the 
`Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor`. If you set it to null, the pointer is hidden. Otherwise you can use the `CoreCursorType` enumeration to set a specific system point. For instance use this to set the Arrow type:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);
```

You can also add custom pointers by using a resource file. For details, [see this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2012/08/01/customcursors-in-windows-8-csharp-metro-applications/).

Comment: I think to custom pointer is too tedious and how do I easy to custom pointer.

Answer (score 19):

No this is not possible to hide cursor but you can use another icons like:

- Hand
- Arrow
- Cross
- Custom
- Hand
- Help
- IBeam

Use xaml Button and add `PointerEntered` event inside Button Control like:

```
<Button Name="button"  BorderThickness="2" PointerEntered="button_PointerEntered"  PointerExited="button_PointerExited">Button</Button>
```

and c# code:

```
 private void button_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Hand, 1);
    }
    private void button_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Arrow, 1);
    }
```

Comment: do you know any way to do this completely in xaml without using code behind?

Comment: Short, Simple, fab explanation! +1

Answer (score 11):

Install the NuGet Package *Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI* from the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/).

After doing so, you can use the following [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/mousecursor):

```
<Page ...
 xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions">

<UIElement extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand"/>
```

Comment: The code above is outdated. Read the updated version here ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/frameworkelementextensions ) or the answer by @NoWar down below.

Answer (score 2):

This example from [Microsoft Community Toolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit)

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:ui="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI">

    <Grid>
        <Border Width="220"
                Height="120"
                Margin="50,100,20,20"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                ui:FrameworkElementExtensions.Cursor="UniversalNo"
                Background="DeepSkyBlue">
            <TextBlock Margin="4"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Element with UniversalNo cursor"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Border>
        <Border Width="220"
                Height="120"
                Margin="20"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                ui:FrameworkElementExtensions.Cursor="Wait"
                Background="Orange">
            <TextBlock Margin="4"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Element with Wait cursor"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Border>

        <Button Margin="20,240,20,20"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Standard button with no custom cursor" />
        <Button Margin="20,290,20,20"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                ui:FrameworkElementExtensions.Cursor="Hand"
                Content="Button with Hand cursor, just like on web" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the cursor in UWP (C++ example)

```
            Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ window = Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
            window->PointerPosition = Point(ScreenXMid, ScreenYMid);
            window->PointerCursor = nullptr;
```