# Change cursor style when rolling over Bing Maps Control UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps

I was wondering if there is a way to change the cursor style while hovering over the Bing Maps Control in UWP/C#? I just want the cross hairs or something like it for picking positions on my Map Control. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956628/change-mouse-pointer-in-uwp-app

Comment: Yes... when you change the cursor on the application and then roll over the bing map control it changes back to the regular arrow. Which is why I asked how to change it on the bing maps control and not how to change the cursor in a UWP app.

Comment: May be I didn't understand, but you can handle the `PointerEntered` event of that Bing map control to change the cursor to cross hair when it enters to Bing Map control, and `PointerExited` event to change the cursor to regular arrow when it leaves the map area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the `PointerEntered()` event to dynamically display the coordinates of the mouse pointer as it hovers over the Map control, but this event is never called. It must be consumed by the control and not passed up the control chain.