# Unable to set Mouse Cursor on Canvas

Tags: uwp

I have a canvas UIElement on my [uwp page](https://github.com/sunsewingmachine/SettingMouseCursor). I am able to successfully set Mouse cursor on any UIElement except the Canvas. I have tried in both a [normal way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956628/change-mouse-pointer-in-uwp-app) and using [community extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.extensions.mouse.setcursor?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable). No luck. Any suggestions?

```
// using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions 
Mouse.SetCursor(this, CoreCursorType.Hand); 
Mouse.SetCursor(MainCanvas, CoreCursorType.Hand);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to set Mouse Cursor on Canvas

The problem is that the Canvas is in the lazy-loading state (without background and children element). Please try to give it specific Background, SetCursor will work.

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="1"  Background="OrangeRed"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Canvas>
```