# How to use a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Symbol as custom pointer in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, mouse-cursor

I'd like to use one of the build in symbols defined in Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Symbol enumeration as cursor like this:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = 
    new CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Custom, Symbol.TouchPointer);
```

But `new CoreCursor` constructor expects argument 2 to be `uint` and it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change mouse pointer in UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956628/change-mouse-pointer-in-uwp-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to use a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Symbol as custom pointer in UWP

UWP does not support use Symbol as [`CoreCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corecursor?view=winrt-19041), if you want to use custom cursor, please *use the CoreCursorType.Custom enumeration option, and specify the Id of the custom cursor. You can add a .res resource file that contains the custom cursor to your project and include it in your assembly with the /win32res compiler option. The Id is the Cursor Resource ID specified in the .res file.*

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/cursor-resource) is the detail document about how to make Cursor Resource ID.